# conditional Regex for Angular-reactive forms input field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[image for regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBgea.png)I am using Angular-reactive forms and using below method

```
password: [
                '',
                [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.pattern(this.passwordRegex),
                ],
paswordRegex = ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}$
```

in HTML I used ngIF condition for form['password'].invalid and wrote password requirement criteria.

But now I need to make conditional type of criteria. Suppose user passed three conditions of regex it should show green color to passed ones and red color to failed ones

```
<mat-error ........................ *ngIf="...">
     <ul>
                 <li> must contain at least one digit</li><!-- condition passed= color=green-->
                 <li> can't start with a digit, underscore or special characters</li><!-- condition passed= color=green-->
                 <li> length must be between 8 to 20 alphanumeric characters</li><!-- condition fail= color=red-->
                 <li> only !@#$% special characters are allowed</li><!-- condition fail= color=red-->
               </ul>
</mat-error>
```

Is it achievable from only front end side?

Comment: you could use custom validation if needed.

Comment: Any example? I am not able to think any scenario

Comment: I've found several for standard custom validation but not directly for multiple constraints/errors. havent tried it yet myself.  just google a bit im sure it exists. sorry

Comment: i have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843538/how-to-differentiate-multiple-validators-pattern

Comment: Might be this helps you http://keepnote.cc/code/angular-2-conditional-validation-reactive-form