# The way to use multiple patterns for one input with Angular 9 Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My app is developed with **Angular 9**, and I have some additional functions needed:

So app looks like that:

**component.ts**:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm()
}

get f() {
    return this.form.controls
}

buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        input: [null, [Validators.pattern('^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+$')]]
    })
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<div *ngIf="f.input.errors.pattern">error message</div>
```

---

**ISSUE:**

There is multiply RegExp conditions: `^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+$`

Is there any way to display error messages for every condition?

e.g.:

```js
Validators.pattern([{'firstLetter': '^[a-z]'}, {'symbols': '^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+$'}])
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843538/how-to-differentiate-multiple-validators-pattern), I tried change code to this, but I cannot handle error with *ngIf:

**component.ts**

```js
regexValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        if (!control.value) {
            return null;
        }
        const valid = regex.test(control.value);
        return valid ? null : error;
    }
}

buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        login: [null, [
            this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[a-z]+$'), {'firstLetter': ''}),
            this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+$'), {'symbols': ''})
        ]],
    })
}
```

**component.html:**

```html
<div *ngIf="f.login.hasError('firstLetter')">error message</div>
<div *ngIf="f.login.hasError('symbols')">error message</div>
```

---

> **SOLUTION:**
>
> Change empty string to true of sting with value:

```js
this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[a-z]+$'), {'firstLetter': true})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843538/how-to-differentiate-multiple-validators-pattern):

**component.ts**

```js
regexValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        if (!control.value) {
            return null;
        }
        const valid = regex.test(control.value);
        return valid ? null : error;
    }
}

buildForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        login: [null, [
            this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[a-z]+$'), {'firstLetter': true}),
            this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+$'), {'symbols': true})
        ]],
    })
}
```

**component.html:**

```html
<div *ngIf="f.login.hasError('firstLetter')">error message</div>
<div *ngIf="f.login.hasError('symbols')">error message</div>
```